# can spring cloud contract handle repeated request with different response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

for example :
both contracts will be calling /api/checkResult

first contract will return a list of result while the latter returning no result (it can happen)

there's no query string or parameters passed in.

I have tried to applied priority but it didnt work, and it always matched to the one with results.

Any idea on how I can proceed?

Comment: don’t think it has been asked before. pls explain

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's called scenarios or stateful contracts. Please read this section of the docs to learn more https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-stateful-contracts